# How to properly handle a null variable perspective in kotlin?

Tags: java, null, kotlin

My old java version method looks like:

```
@Override
public void closeSimpleAlertDialog() {
    if (mAlertDialog != null && mAlertDialog.isShowing()) {
        mAlertDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

As you can tell it is checked whether the null reference link to a dialog `mAlertDialog` and if not null check call method `isShowing()`, and only then caused a method of close - `dismiss()`. Very simple

I faced a problem - how is still in "Kotlin-style" to perform the same operation?

My first version looks here:

```
if (mAlertDialog != null && mAlertDialog?.isShowing) {
        mAlertDialog?.dismiss()
}
```

Next step change `mAlertDialog != null && mAlertDialog?.isShowing` to `mAlertDialog?.isShowing ?: false` and last version looks like:

```
if (mAlertDialog?.isShowing ?: false)
            mAlertDialog?.dismiss()
```

But I don't understand. Why do I need "?" if the null checking already happened before (here: `mAlertDialog?.`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because another thread might make the property null after the null check, and before the call to dismiss. It won't happen if you use a local variable, or `let`.

BTW, if you omit the question mark and hover on the red squiggly, IntelliJ tells you

> Smart cast to Dialog is impossible, because mAlertDialog is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time

The canonical way (AFAIK) to do that with Kotlin would be

```
fun close() {
    mAlertDialog?.let { 
        if (it.isShowing) {
            it.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Another way would be `mAlertDialog?.takeIf { it.isShowing }?.dismiss()`.

Answer (score 4):

```
mAlertDialog?.isShowing ?: false
```

This line is providing a fallback value (false) in case the dialog or the property is null.

What you are probably looking for is:

```
alertDialog?.let {
    if (it.isShowing())
        it.dismiss()
}
```

Where "it" is the property before the question mark null-checked.
If alertDialog is null, the let will not be called and note that if you call it without the question mark it will enter even if it's null.

Comment: hm, i understand this. my secondary question is - why we needed in "?" here: mAlertDialog>>?<<.dismiss() if we checked this before. Here: (mAlertDialog?.isShowing ?: false).

Answer (score 0):

If you use `?` then you are allowing the null value for the variables.

**Example:**

```
var a: String = "abc"
a = null // compilation error

var b: String? = "abc"
b = null // ok

b?.length
```

This returns b.length if b is not null, and null otherwise.